# Reloading Dynamic Controls

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that makes use of dynamic controls, however if the user makes a mistake and enters the wrong number into a textbox they receive the wrong number of dynamic controls for example:

If a user enters 5 in my textbox they will receive 5 listboxs but if they then decide that they need 3 listboxs instead of 5 they will still see 5 listboxs because the dynamic controls haven't been removed and added again.

I know that I could reset the entire form but I don't want to do this because there is information in fixed controls that I want to keep available to the user. So what I am trying to ask is: Is it possible to remove and add dynamic controls during run time? I have read numerous articles on this matter but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the control references in an array/collection/whatever, you can loop through that and delete all the ones you created - or only delete the difference in number e.g. the last two.

Comment: so store the dynamic controls in an array and then loop through an array to display them, I think that coiuld work if I'm thinking along the right lines. I will give that a go and see how I get on with that! I knew this was a difficult question to ask so i'm glad I got an answer

Comment: I assume you're doing that anyway, from previous questions, otherwise you can't handle their events.

Comment: yes they are in an array already, i'm gunna try and clear the array and reload it then :)

Comment: You can't simply clear the array - you have to loop through it and use the Userform.Controls.Remove method passing the name of the stored control.